# Is there a to perform animation/movement to uitableviewcell after cell is created?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is what i want, i have a tableview with 3 custom cells. Each cell performs different functions and the cell 2 needs info from cell 1, and cell 3 needs info from cell 2. So to make it a bit more intuitive, i am trying to perform a cell movement in cell 2(moving from outside screen to inside screen,i.e slide-in) when a button in cell 1 is clicked. Basically i am trying to move a cell from outside to the view to inside the view when a button is created.

Unfortunately this crashes, normally this kind of movement works in normal cases but will crash on a TableView.

Is it possible to perform movement by using CGAffine once a cell is displayed ?

This is the function i am using,which i made for easy usage.

```
func movementAnimation(duration:Double,X:CGFloat,Y:CGFloat,item:UIView)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
      item.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: X, y: Y)

    }
}
```

The function to move view into display area on button press. This is done inside button action inside the cell class.

```
 @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

movementAnimation(duration: 0.5, X: 0, Y: 0, item: viewDate)


    }
```

This is basically a slide-in situation.

Is there a way around this make this movement without crashing?

Comment: Can you attach screenshot with a crash?

Comment: @MikeHaydan It just crashes with ``Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file``

Comment: I think the problem has to be in something else, not in animation, because tableview cell is just a view and you can do with it whatever you want. Try to use `exception breakpoint`, I hope it will help to detect where issue came from

Comment: @MikeHaydan I fixed it and i am going to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging around i found a way to bypass this issue.

I made a simple notification to check when the button has been pressed. On cell class,

```
    @IBAction func ActionPaymentOne(_ sender: Any) {

         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: 
    Notification.Name("moveAnimation"), object: nil)

    }
```

Now on the tableViewController Class , i added this on viewDidLoad()

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(self.moveAnimation(notification:)), name: 
Notification.Name("moveAnimation"), object: nil)
```

Now i added the function for this

```
@objc func moveAnimation(notification: Notification)
    {
        let index = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        let currentCell = Table.cellForRow(at: index)! as! PaymentsTableViewCell
        movementAnimation(duration: 0.5, X: 0, Y: 0, item: currentCell.viewDate)
    }
```

Since i know which cell, i simply made a static index value. If someone wants to do this for any random cell, you could do this by getting the cell path from tag or button press delegates.